# Tell tcpdump to skip custom header

Tags: linux, tcpdump, wireshark

I have an IP packet with x bytes of custom header coming in on an interface. Is there a way to tell `tcpdump` or `tshark` to ignore the first x bytes and decode and display the IP packet? Any pointers would be helpful; I don't want to write a custom discector

Comment: I wonder if you could use wireshark instead. You could try the `Disable Protocol`, it helped me to skip a socks header.

Comment: @ott-- i have only command line access

Comment: then write your pcap based sniffer

Comment: See http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5613/disable-protocol-dissection-in-tshark/5624

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark's `editcap` has a "chop" feature (`-C`) which can top and tail packets for exactly this purpose.

You can do it real-time like this:

```
 tcpdump -w - [...filter...] | editcap -F libpcap -C 16 - - | tcpdump -nlvvv -r -
```